# PHP 5.3 vs 5.4 : 'this' showing up as undefined variable in object

Tags: php, porting

I'm having issues with code that worked fine in PHP 5.3 and is now broken in PHP 5.4.  The original environments where the code works are:

Ubuntu 11.04
Lighttpd 1.4.29
PHP 5.3

and

Mac OSX 10.7.4
Apache 2.0.63
PHP 5.3

and the new environment is:

Android 4.0.4
Lighttpd 1.4.29
PHP 5.4.4

I've boiled down the problem code to two simple files:

[test.class.php]

```
class Test {
    public $testProp1;
    
    function setTestProp1($value){
        $this->testProp1 = $value;
        return ($this->testProp1 != '') ? true : false;
    }
    
    function doSomething()
    {
        if( $this->testProp1 )
        { echo "Just do some " . $this->testProp1; }
        else
        { echo "Just do nothing"; }
    }

}
```

[debug.php]

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require "test.class.php";

$myTest = new Test();
$myTest->setTestProp1("foo");

$myTest->doSomething();
```

On the system with PHP 5.3, the output is:

Just do some foo

On the system with PHP 5.4, the output is:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /data/www/test.class.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: this in /data/www/test.class.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /data/www/test.class.php on line 11

Just do nothing

---

Even if I change the error reporting level, I still get the warning and 'Just do nothing' in PHP 5.4.  Not sure what the deal is, I'm totally stumped.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Works fine for me - http://ignite.io/code/50183befef167b7e64000000

Comment: Thanks, but does Ignite allow you to select which version of PHP you want to use?  I haven't used Ignite before and didn't see a place where you could specify that.

Comment: Echoing PHP_VERSION shows they're running 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8, which is the version the OP is reporting as doing the right thing.

Comment: Works fine for me on PHP 5.4 (Zend Server CE, Windows). I can't see anything wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this on another install of PHP 5.4.4 on Mac OSX and it worked fine.  We're thinking something went wrong when we ported PHP to Android so we'll have to revisit that process.  In the future will definitely test more configurations before posting on SO.

Thanks everyone.